# Export a collection of featureCollections as CSV?

Tags: export-to-csv, flatten, google-earth-engine

Sampling daily data but unable to export:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ca236ee4e12cffb398f62465bc413e68

the bug should be somewhere between line 272 and 285.

Using .flatten() returns an empty collection!

thank you in advance,

Andrea

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The code is available in the body of the text